# Does the following distribution converge to anything?

Tags: normal-distribution, convergence, extreme-value

Consider the following process for generating a random sample:

- Sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$
- Compute $M = \max\limits_i |X_i|$
- Scale the values to get $Z_i = X_i / M$

Can we say anything about the convergence of distribution of $Z_i$ as $n\to\infty$?

The $Z_i$s are clearly identically distributed, but they aren't independent since for any $n$ almost certainly exactly 1 $Z_i$ will take the value -1 or 1.

Here's what the points are distributed like for various values of $n$ (65,000 trials each):

$n=16$
[image]

$n=64$
[image]

$n=4,096$
[image]

These all use 100 evenly spaced bins, hence the spikes at the ends for the smaller values of $n$. Does the limiting distribution have a name?

Edit: I should clarify that the obvious candidate thing for it to converge to would be a point mass on 0, but I'm not sure whether it does that or not.

Renamed $Y$ to $Z$ for consistency with the plots.

Comment: If the cdf for $Y_n$ is $F_n$, and the cdf of the standard normal is $\Phi$, then I would expect $F_n(x E[M_n]) \to \Phi(x)$.

Comment: I don't think the support works out there does it?

Comment: This q&a may be helpful:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables.

Comment: I think it works — where do you think it doesn’t?

Comment: For some $N$, $n > N \implies E[M_n] > 1$, at which point $n > N \implies F_n(-2 E[M_n]) = 0$, but $\Phi(-2) \neq 0$

Comment: Maybe add the tag "extreme-value"?

Comment: Standardize the $Y_i$ and redraw your histograms.

Comment: @whuber Do you mean standardize over all samples represented in this histogram? Or separately for each draw of N examples?

Comment: What is `Z_i` and how does it relate to $Y_i$ and $X_i$? It would be much clearer to [edit] to only use one name, instead of sticking a note at the end. The edit history will preserve previous versions in case anyone wants to have a look.

Comment: I'll just change it to Z everywhere. I was going to switch to Y to avoid confusion with the standard normal.

Comment: You are asking a question about *random variables,* not draws. The standardization therefore changes their scale and location as a function of $n$ to assure that any $Z_i$ even can converge in distribution to something.

Comment: A process like this _could_ converge to some distribution supported on [-1, 1]. Is your answer that the mass just gets more and more concentrated near the origin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$Z$ converges to point mass at zero.  We know $M_n\stackrel{p}{\to}\infty$ since the Normal distribution is unbounded.

So, for any fixed $\epsilon$ and any $i$, $$P(|Z_i|>\epsilon)=P(|X_i/M_n|>\epsilon)\to 0$$
implying $Z_i\stackrel{p}{\to} 0$ and  $Z_i\stackrel{d}{\to} 0$.

The convergence will be quite slow, because $M_n$ increases roughly as $\sqrt{\log n}$. It's going to be relatively hard to get convincing simulations for the Gaussian case.

Comment: Usually this kind of convergence statement is of little use, as in this case, because the sequence, properly normalized, *does converge* to a Normal distribution.

Comment: This is actually for a practical application, in which the choice of normalizing is not available: https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.14314

(There's a lot of stuff going on in that paper, only the NF4 data type stuff is relevant here)

Comment: That's a fascinating paper, thank you.  But this sounds rather like an X/Y problem: if the issue is with low-precision floating point computation, the question you asked scarcely looks relevant.

Comment: It's relevant because the way the quantization algorithm works is to take a batch of values, then divide them by the max absolute value to scale them into [-1, 1]. The authors propose a discretization of [-1, 1] based on quantiles of the normal distribution. The reason for my question is that I was wondering whether there was some known distribution the quantiles should be calculated from instead.

Comment: That doesn't sound like "the choice of normalizing is not available"!

Comment: Dividing by the sample standard deviation would give us values with quite large support and the method really would not work well at all.

Comment: @whuber I'd like to acknowledge you wherever I end up writing this up. Can you drop me an email at dyoshida@ttic.edu?

Answer (score 3):

The following demonstration is not rigorous, but it's correct :-).

Because the Normal distribution is continuous, there is almost surely a unique maximum absolute value.  Thus, the chance that $|Z_n|=1$ is $1/n.$ In all other cases $Z_n = X_n/X_i$ where $X_i$ attains the maximum absolute value.  Furthermore, for extremely large $n,$ the standard deviation of the distribution of that maximum $M_n$ shrinks towards zero as $n$ grows.  Consequently, $M_n$ is nearly constant and will necessarily be close to its median.

Because the CDF of the maximum is $\Phi(x)^n,$ its median $m_n$ is where $\Phi(m_n)^n = 1/2,$ so that

$$M_n \approx m_n = \Phi^{-1}(2^{-1/n}).$$

Thus,

> $Z_n$ will (with probability $1-1/n$) be arbitrarily close to $X_n/m_n,$ which has a mean-zero Normal distribution with standard deviation $1/m_n.$

In a simulation of $5\,000$ samples, each of size $50\,000,$  I computed all the $Z_n.$  Here are histograms for four selected values of $n.$  Over them I have plotted the Normal approximation.  The p-value is that obtained by removing the values of $Z_n$ equal to $1$ (we know they contribute a small "atom") and applying a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to the rest.

[image]

Even with this $5\,000$ samples, the KS test -- which is notorious for its power to distinguish Normal from non-Normal data (some people on this site have claimed it will *always* reject Normality on any dataset this large) -- does not reject the foregoing claim when $n = 50\,000.$

More specifically, upon dividing $Z_n$ by the standard deviation $1/m_n,$ we find **the distribution of $Z_n \Phi^{-1}(2^{-1/n})$ converges to the standard Normal distribution.**  An immediate consequence is that the distribution of $Z_n$ converges to zero *at a rate given by $1 / \Phi^{-1}(2^{-1/n}).$*  This is a slow rate, because a crude approximation gives $m_n = O(1/\sqrt{\log n}).$  For instance, $1/m_n=1/10$ for $n \approx e^{100} \approx 10^{43}$ and a standard deviation of $1/10$ is still appreciable. Thus, in any application it would usually be unwise to approximate $Z_n$ by $0:$ use this limiting Normal distribution instead as a better approximation.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis! I'll try this out as a quantization grid and see how it works.

Comment: I think that should be $Z_n \times \Phi^-1(2^{-1/n})$ right? If you divide by a quantity which is growing in $n$ it'll still converge to 0.

Comment: Of course--thanks for the correction.  I see another typo to fix, too...

Comment: There's one other issue, which is that rather than $\Phi^{-1}$, one should use the inverse CDF of the half-normal distribution (since $M$ is the max absolute value), but that's easy to implement.

Comment: Actually, that's not needed -- but it's a great suggestion and would be better insofar as it more clearly indicates the role played by this quantity.

Comment: It pretty noticeably affects the quality of the approximation in my numerical experiments (comparing quantiles computed using this approximation to sample quantiles).

Comment: Yes, it would for small $n.$  (Although in this case, given my remarks about the slow asymptotics, "small" might be pretty big ;-).